# Trying to display cards in a row but card-deck isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My cards aren't being displayed horizontally could anyone help?

code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Character.Classes" class="control-label"></label>
     <div>
         <div class="container-fluid padding">
             <div class="card-deck">
                 @foreach (var item in Model.Classes)
                 {
                     <div class="card bg-secondary shadow-lg" style="width:18rem;">
                         <div class="card-columns">
                             <h4 class="card-title">
                                 <label><input asp-for="Character.Classes" value="@item.Name" type="radio" />@item.Name</label>
                             </h4>
                             <p class="card-text">
                                 <label>Hitdie = D</label>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hitdie)
                             </p>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label asp-for="Character.Level" class="control-label"></label>
                                 <input asp-for="Character.Level" class="form-control" />
                                 <span asp-validation-for="Character.Level" class="text-danger"></span>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                             <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 }
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

 </div>
```

I tried using card-deck and row but neither changed how the cards are displayed

Comment: Hi, which Bootstrap version you used? Have you include Bootstrap CSS file in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your Bootstrap (with version 4.X) file is imported into the HTML. [Card decks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks) is only available in Bootstrap version 4.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

---

If you are using Bootstrap 5, you need to follow the [migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#card) as mentioned in the documentation.

> - Dropped `.card-deck` in favor of our grid. Wrap your cards in column classes and add a parent `.row-cols-*` container to recreate card decks (but with more control over responsive alignment).
> - Dropped `.card-columns` in favor of Masonry.

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
                 
    @foreach (var item in Model.Classes)
    {
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card bg-secondary shadow-lg" style="width:18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <label><input asp-for="Character.Classes" value="@item.Name" type="radio" />@item.Name</label>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <label>Hitdie = D</label>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hitdie)
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Character.Level" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Character.Level" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Character.Level" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>
                </div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

-> in this code using Bootstrap's class 'card-deck'.

-> in your code, i added to the card-deck class in to div directly and added row div to wrap the crad-deck div. because appyly that cards are displayed in row.

-> Please add boostrap link in your layout :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

-> Code:-

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="Character.Classes" class="control-label"></label>
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-deck">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Classes)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- Adjust the column size as needed -->
                    <div class="card bg-secondary shadow-lg">
                        <div class="card-columns">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                <label><input asp-for="Character.Classes" value="@item.Name" type="radio" />@item.Name</label>
                            </h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <label>Hitdie = D</label>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hitdie)
                            </p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Character.Level" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Character.Level" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Character.Level" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row pb-3">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row p-2">
                <div class="col-12 p-1">
                    <div class="card border-0 p-3 shadow  border-top border-5 rounded"> 
                        @if(product.ProductImages!=null && product.ProductImages.Count() > 0) {
                            <img src="@product.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl" class="card-img-top rounded" />
                        }
                        else {
                            <img src="https://placehold.co/500x600/png" class="card-img-top rounded" />
                        }
                        
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <div class="pl-1">
                                <p class="card-title h5 text-dark opacity-75 text-uppercase text-center">@product.Title</p>
                                <p class="card-title text-warning text-center">by <b>@product.Author</b></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-1">
                                <p class="text-dark text-opacity-75 text-center mb-0">
                                    List Price: 
                                    <span class="text-decoration-line-through">
                                        @product.ListPrice.ToString("c")
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-1">
                                <p class="text-dark text-opacity-75 text-center">As low as: 
                                    <span>
                                        @product.Price100.ToString("c")
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a asp-action="Details"
                            asp-route-productId="@product.Id"
                            class="btn btn-primary bg-gradient border-0 form-control">
                                Details
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```